# text contents of pdf to csv file conversion- How to?

Tags: python, csv, pdf, tabula

I want to take a PDF File as an input. And as an output file I want a csv file to show. So all the textual data which is there in the pdf file should be converted to a csv file. But I am not understanding how would this happen..I need your help at the earliest as I've tried to do but couldn't do it.

what ive done is used a library called Tabula-py which converts pdf to csv file. It does create a csv format but there are no contents being copied to the csv file from the pdf file.

heres the code

```
from tabula import convert_into,read_pdf
import tabula
df = tabula.read_pdf("crimestory.pdf", spreadsheet=True, 
                     pages='all',output_format="csv")
df.to_csv('crimestoryy.csv', index=False)
```

the output should come as a csv file where the data is present.
what i am getting is a blank csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have **find** answer to this question by my own
To tackle this issue I came up with converting the pdf file into a text file. Then I converted this text file to a csv file.here's my code.

conversion.py

```
import os.path
import csv
import pdftotext
#Load your PDF
with open("crimestory.pdf", "rb") as f:
   pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

# Save all text to a txt file.
with open('crimestory.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("\n\n".join(pdf))

save_path = "/home/mayureshk/PycharmProjects/NLP/"

completeName_in = os.path.join(save_path, 'crimestory' + '.txt')
completeName_out = os.path.join(save_path, 'crimestoryycsv' + '.csv')

file1 = open(completeName_in)
In_text = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')

file2 = open(completeName_out, 'w')
out_csv = csv.writer(file2)

file3 = out_csv.writerows(In_text)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it will works

```
import tabula

# convert PDF into CSV
tabula.convert_into("crimestory.pdf", "crimestory.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')
```

or

```
df = tabula.read_pdf("crimestory.pdf", encoding='utf-8', spreadsheet=True, pages='all')
df.to_csv('crimestory.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

or

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df = read_pdf("crimestory.pdf")
df
#make sure df displays your pdf contents in the output

from tabula import convert_into
convert_into("crimestory.pdf", "crimestory.csv", output_format="csv")
!cat.crimestory.csv
```

Comment: The first one again shows an empty csv file.. whereas the second one is giving  a TypeError:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
@Kalana Eranda Jayasuriya

Comment: can you rename the output file into another name and run the first code again

Comment: I did it but its showing no contents in the csv file. its a blank csv file

Comment: If it didn't work rename `pages='all'` to `pages='1-<enter ending page number>'` then run it

Comment: I have add another code to my answer please check it,

Comment: The code works however its displaying some infos. like heres the output on my terminal -- INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font Times New Roman,Italic are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
Sep 23, 2019 11:55:59 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font Arial are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
Sep 23, 2019 11:55:59 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2 <init>
INFO: OpenType Layout tables used in font Times New Roman,Italic are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored

Comment: Is `crimestory.csv` genarated when you used 3rd code

Comment: it generated a blank csv file... so to workaround i tried converting this pdf to a text file then text file to a csv file! and it worked !

Comment: comment that solution in hear as an answer. It will help lot of developers who have faced like your issue

Answer (score 1):

Tabula-py is used to read only tables in the pdf document